# How to show postmeta in custom columns for the posts screen?

Tags: wp-admin, advanced-custom-fields

I've got a True/False value added to posts (Exclusive versus Curated) that was added via Advanced Custom Fields. How do I get that value to show up as a column on the Post list (/wp-admin/edit.php) to allow editors to quickly sort via that field?

I found this example (http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/add-a-custom-column-in-posts-and-custom-post-types-admin-screen--wp-24934) for adding the post thumbnail, but do not know how to adjust to pull and ACF field in instead.

Field name is company_exclusive and type is True/False.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Edit: I found this solution (http://olliebarker.co.uk/articles/2014/06/displaying-custom-fields-wordpress-admin-post-lists/), and adapted its code to my needs, but after creating this, I'm not seeing the fields in on wp-admin/edit.php screen (either in Screen options or visible). I'm adding it to my theme's functions.php. That is the right place, correct?

```
//Adds ACF fields to Post List
add_filter('posts_columns', 'custom_posts_table_head');
function custom_posts_table_head( $columns ) {

    $columns['author_name']  = 'Author Name';
    $columns['company_exclusive']  = 'Company Exclusive?';
    $columns['region']  = 'Region';
    $columns['article_excerpt_title']  = 'Article Excerpt Title';
    return $columns;

}
add_action( 'posts_columns', 'custom_posts_table_content', 10, 2);

function bs_projects_table_content( $column_name, $post_id ) {

    if( $column_name == 'author_name' ) {
        $author_name = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'author_name', true );
        echo $author_name;
    }
    if( $column_name == 'company_exclusive' ) {
        $company_exclusive = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'company_exclusive', true );
        if( $company_exclusive == '1' ) { echo 'Yes'; } else { echo 'No'; }
    }
    if( $column_name == 'region' ) {
        $region = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'region', true );
        echo $region;
    }
    if( $column_name == 'article_excerpt_title' ) {
        $article_excerpt_title = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'article_excerpt_title', true );
        echo $article_excerpt_title;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You've got your action/filter names slightly off:

```
// For registering the column
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'custom_posts_table_head' );

// For rendering the column
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'custom_posts_table_content', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Simply changing those action/filter names lines, I get a slew of errors on the edit.php screen, starting with: `Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'custom_posts_table_head' not found or invalid function name in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs-lenovo-health-wp/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 213`

Comment: The error is pretty explanatory - are you sure you have the function in your code?

Comment: New to this.. I just had the code in my original question in my theme's functions.php.  Do I have to call the function somewhere within the wp-admin subdir as well?

Answer (score 2):

I used following code to specify featured products in admin panel product list.

```
add_filter('manage_product_posts_columns', 'hs_product_table_head');
function hs_product_table_head( $columns ) {
    $columns['product_featured']  = 'Featured';
    return $columns;

}
add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'hs_product_table_content', 10, 2 );

function hs_product_table_content( $column_name, $post_id ) {
    if( $column_name == 'product_featured' ) {
        $featured_product = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'featured_product', true );
        if($featured_product == 1) {
            echo "Yes";
        }
    }
}
```

To use this for other post types - change the following code. For example - post type is "portfolio"

```
add_filter('manage_portfolio_posts_columns', 'hs_portfolio_table_head');
add_action( 'manage_portfolio_posts_custom_column', 'hs_portfolio_table_content', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

For Advanced Custom Fields, put this code in `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'manage_faq_posts_columns', 'set_custom_edit_faq_columns' );    
add_action( 'manage_faq_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_faq_column', 10, 2 );

function set_custom_edit_faq_columns($columns) {    
    unset( $columns['author'] );
    $columns['is_useful'] = 'Is Useful';
    $columns['is_unless'] = 'Is Unless';
    return $columns;    
}

function custom_faq_column( $column, $post_id ) {   
    global $post;
    switch ( $column ) {
        case 'is_useful' :
            if(get_field( "is_useful", $post_id )) {
                echo get_field( "is_useful", $post_id );
            } else {
                echo 0;
            }
        break;

        case 'is_unless' :
            if(get_field( "is_unless", $post_id )) {
                echo get_field( "is_unless", $post_id );
            } else {
                echo 0;
            }
        break;    
    }   
}

function my_column_register_sortable( $columns ) {
     $columns['is_useful'] = 'is_useful';
    $columns['is_unless'] = 'is_unless';
    return $columns;
}

add_filter("manage_edit-faq_sortable_columns", "my_column_register_sortable" );
```

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Please do not just dump code but explain it with code comments or a short paragraph about how it works. For you it is obvious, but someone else might not understand what it does just by looking at the code.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a plugin that does exactly what you need without writing any line of code - Posts Columns Manager - https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-columns-manager/.

You can add any custom fields to your posts overview page just with a few clicks.

It supports custom post types, any meta fields, and even fields generated by the ACF plugin.

Comment: I suppose your plugin does contain a few lines of code? ;-)

Comment: @HerbertVan-Vliet Sure, it just means that I've written those lines for you :)